# How to POST a form using Jersey 2.0

Tags: java, html, rest, jersey, jax-ws

I am trying to get some data from a Form with jersey and i though it would be an easy task to accomplish, however I am getting an error when I try to POST something.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueFactoryProvider$FormParamValueFactory.ensureValidRequest(FormParamValueFactoryProvider.java:126)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueFactoryProvider$FormParamValueFactory.getForm(FormParamValueFactoryProvider.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueFactoryProvider$FormParamValueFactory.get(FormParamValueFactoryProvider.java:94)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.provide(AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:80)
... 36 more
```

I think this is the relevant part of the stack trace.
Now for the code I am using:

```
@POST
@Path("/delete")
@Produces("application/json")
public String delete(@FormParam("id")String id){
```

And I am trying to POST using a test html page like this:

```
<form action="<path to the server>/delete" method="post">
    primary_id: <input type="text" name="primary_id" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I've been trying to make it work but no chance. I have tried adding the @Consumes() annotation with multipart-form-data but can't really make it work. I hope someone can give me a hand.

Comment: try Consumes(application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: i've tried but had the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. With some code reviewing i found the problem. Even though I don't think anyone else will make this particular mistake I'll post it anyway for future reference.

The problem was that I am not using a standard web server. I've implemented a netty server with Jersey and the problem was in that said implementation. The problem was that i wasn't passing the headers in the HTTP request to Jersey as I should. I was loosing the Content-Type in the middle of the operation, this means that Jersey couldn't identify the message type.

So, for future reference, for anyone having a similar problem while trying to implement a non-standard server using jersey: when you don't pass the media type correctly (there is a method called getMediaType() in the ContentRequest class that is used, among other things, to validate the Content-Type when @FormParam is used) you will get this type of Exception.

Again, thank you all for the help :)

Comment: Can you give out an example of how you did it?

Comment: well, it was 5 years ago and I don't quite remember the specifics. Your question is about binding jersey to netty or just how I passed the headers?

Comment: I implemented, at the time, a handler for netty that would have knowledge of the ApplicationHandler from jersey. When a message was received I read the request, created a ContainerRequest (since this is the object that Jersey is expecting) and then handle the application level, via ApplicationHandler that I had knowledge about. I then had a netty ContainerResponseWriter that handled the response to the client. About the headers, you should look at InboundMessageContext from jersey which is extended by ContainerRequest and will probably tell you what you need. Anything I can help with just ask.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine except you need to change

```
<input type="text" name="id" />
```

Since you havent define @Consumes(), by default delete method consumes `mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" .`

I have tested your code and it is working perfectly fine here. My suggestion is check your jersey jar files Specially jsersey-server.jar file in your lib folder.

Comment: indeed all you said was true and i thank you for the help. After checking other classes I found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are naming your input as "primary_id", but you are receiving "id" name in your @FormParm annotation. Change the id and name in your input tag to "id".

Also if you are consuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded, add this attribute to your form tag: enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: I am very thankful for the help but the "primary_id" was a typo. I've tried with curl too. I am getting a little desperate. I've also tried with enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded". No luck.

Comment: Weird.. Make sure all libs are the same version (e.g. 1.13).

Comment: actually, as i said in the title I am using jersey 2.0. Anyway i found the problem I'll post it for future reference even though I don't really think anyone will have a similar problem :)